# Get unique EmailAddress and append desired column values to one field by query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vbscript

am working on **access database** and i have a table similar to below table

```
Email Address            Prog_Name    
====================================
jesse@gmail.com     data processing
onesh@gmail.com     big data
jesse@gmail.com     big data
```

i want to get results in the form of below  thru **query** or **vb script**.

```
Email Address            Prog_Name    
====================================
jesse@gmail.com     data processing / big data
onesh@gmail.com     big data
```

tried some methods,but didn't get better result on it..
thanks in advance...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478272/converting-mysql-code-to-access-group-concat-and-a-triple-join check this link may help you

Comment: Look at [Domain Function](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to your problem:

```
SELECT [Email Address], 
       ConcatRelated("Prog_Name", "Table1", "[Email Address] = " & [Email Address],""," / ")
FROM Table1
```

Follow the below link for more info:

> http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

To add the `ConcatRelated` Function Follow the below steps:

1. In Access, open the code window (e.g. press Ctrl+G.)
2. On the Insert menu, click Module. Access opens a new module window.
3. Paste in the function [link](http://collabedit.com/6jawg).
4. On the Debug menu, click Compile, to ensure Access understands it.

The above Function is Provided by **Allen Browne**.

Comment: hi nishant, thanks for the link,Actually this should have done the work but ....its popping an error saying **"undefined function 'ConcatRelated' in the expression"** any idea what might be the reason..thanks